# Browserify complains about missing Coffee-Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, gruntjs, browserify

Being very new to both Javascript, angular and browserify I am trying to browserify a small project, specifically in this case a simple unit test. Browserifying the app.js file worked flawlessly, but now i want to do the same to the unit tests following this "guide":

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/angularjs-browserify/

I pretty much have the same code, just modified it a bit. Testing it in a browser after browserifying it seems to work fine.

However when i browserify the unittest i get this error:

```
amir:/Users/amir/projects/angular-browserify-poc$ browserify test/spec/domain1/domain1_controllerSpec.js --outfile test/spec/browserified/browserified_domain1_tests.js    
Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script' from '/Users/amir/projects/angular-browserify-poc/node_modules/karma/lib'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:50:17
    at process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:119:43)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:128:21
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:60:43)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:66:22
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:21:47
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

I have no idea why it is complaining about Coffee-Script? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install dependencies with `npm install`. Apparently, `/Users/amir/projects/angular-browserify-poc/node_modules/karma/lib` requires module `coffee-script` and cannot find it.

Also, check if there isn't any CoffeeScript files in the specs and the configuration which are prompting karma to use the CoffeeScript compiler.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I still don't understand why it would complain about something that isn't being used though, seems odd to me.